# baffling python datetime.strptime() "does not match format" error

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a Django project that is running on a live CentOS production server. I last updated code about 9 days ago, and everything had been working fine until today. Suddenly, I started getting a baffling error that makes no sense. Here is my traceback:

```
[Fri Nov 04 18:43:00 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/tethys/src/tethys_apps/tethysapp/hydroshare_gis/utilities.py", line 1196, in res_has_been_updated
[Fri Nov 04 18:43:00 2016] [error]     db_date_obj = datetime.strptime(db_date.split('+')[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%X.%f')
[Fri Nov 04 18:43:00 2016] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
[Fri Nov 04 18:43:00 2016] [error]     (data_string, format))
[Fri Nov 04 18:43:00 2016] [error] ValueError: time data '2016-10-15T15:12:41.787370' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%X.%f'
```

Here is the function that throws the error, pretty straight forward:

```
def res_has_been_updated(db_date, res_date):
    db_date_obj = datetime.strptime(db_date.split('+')[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%X.%f')
    res_date_obj = datetime.strptime(res_date.split('+')[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%X.%f')
    if db_date_obj < res_date_obj:
        return True

    return False
```

I temporarily added a few print statements to double-check the dates coming in, and this is what they look like:

```
2016-06-14T13:30:42.735448+00:00
```

Now call me crazy, but I must disagree with this python interpreter... That time data *does* match the format. How am I so sure? 1) I have eyes. 2) This was working fine before today (I have not modified the code and the inputs have not changed). And 3) I hard-coded the exact line into a python console, like so `datetime.strptime('2016-06-14T13:30:42.735448+00:00'.split('+')[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%X.%f')` and it worked.

Though I am the only developer that touches code dealing with this particular project, there are others who access the server for maintenance and other activity. I know that a few python modules were recently installed (matplotlib for one), and someone implemented supervisord to handle process control on the server. Though I don't see why those would effect the validity of a standard python call. I could use any genius and/or brilliance out there. Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. `datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-10-15T15:12:41.787370', '%Y-%m-%dT%X.%f')` works fine, as you say.

Comment: The change you made 9 days ago, is it related? Is it possible that you forgot to restart the server and the old code had been running? Also, do the print statements direct their output to a file? Have you opened that file, say in vim, to check that there aren't any invisible characters inside the string? Can you also check the format string and make sure it has no invisible characters and that Y (and T and X) are really the English characters they're supposed to be? (e.g. there are Greek characters that look exactly the same but are different.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we uninstalled supervisord from the server, and then the error went away. Very strange. I will mark the question as answered although we still do not know exactly why supervisord causes a standard python module to malfunction... We will turn to them for further assistance.